# Print user's input in output?

Tags: python, list, input, output

I have a list of approximately 5 items and it is about a football oracle, where the user types in the two teams and then the program picks out an answer randomly from the mentioned list. 
So I'd like to have the user's input considered when it comes to answering the question because at the moment it is just a general sentence.
So for instance, if the user types in "Manchester United" as the home team and "FC Basel" as the guest team, I'd like the program to answer with using the names instead of **Home team**.
But how could I possibly do that?

Comment: please show us your attempt at this before asking for help

Comment: So write a program to do that stuff

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show some code to help you with :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
teams = [] #list of the teams that will be in "competition"
hometeam = input("Who is the home team? ").title()
teams.append(hometeam) #adds this team to the list
awayteam = input("Who is the away team? ").title()
teams.append(awayteam) #adds this team to the list
print(random.choice(teams)) #chooses random item in the list and prints it
```